# VBA for Excel Returns All Children When Calling .ParentNode

Tags: excel, xml, vba

Trying to return the value of employee's manager, but getting all the information for that employee.

```
Set xObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

xObj.async = False
xObj.validateOnParse = Fase
xObj.Load (XMLFile)

Dim list As Object
Dim node As Object
Dim login As Object

Set list = xObj.getElementsByTagName("employeeLogin")

For Each login In list
    If login.Text <> "Not Found" Then
            Debug.Print login.Text
            Debug.Print login.ParentNode.Text
    End If
Next
```

Just using the debug window for now to test everything. I expect it to print the employee's login followed by the manager's login. Instead it prints the manager's login, plus all the information for the employee. Repeats that for each employee under each manager.
e.g.
I'm getting

managerlogin employeelogin employeetitle employeestartdate......

managerlogin employee2login employee2title employee2startdate....

...

...

manager2login employeelogin employeetitle employeestartdate......

manager2login employee2login employee2title employee2startdate....

Comment: Try `Debug.Print login.nodeTypedValue`

Comment: a) Please edit a rough structure of your xml hierarchy for better understanding your needs; b) omit the needless brackets within `xObj.Load (XMLFile); c) would suggest version 6.0
`